# How to implement horizontal scroller with ImageViews

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

I would like to displaying set of Images downloaded from web and display it as part of bottom horizontal thumbnail view,in horizontal scroll view mode,whenever i take photos,it needs to be added to list of images in bottom.

What type of native component to be used,I tried recycler view and horizontalGridView(LeanBack V17 APIs,a extension of recycler view),in both of them,I am getting horizontal scrolling issues,which I am not able to fix it out,[(scroll issue related to recycle view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333274/regarding-properscrolling-in-horizontal-recycler-view)

Is there anyother alternative native APIs that can be used for achieving the horizontal listview of Images.

Comment: Share your `Recyclerview` code what you have tried.

Comment: I have already posted in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333274/regarding-properscrolling-in-horizontal-recycler-view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use LinearLayout with attribute
 `android:orientation="horizontal"`

You also need to put this LinearLayout in ScrollLayout to have scroll over it.

When the image is downloaded, you can add it in ImageView inside LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    Activity:

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    adapter = new EventListAdapter(this, imageList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Adapter:
    public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private final LayoutInflater inflator;
    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> imageList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.imageList = imageList;

        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.eventlistadapterdata, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Integer image = imageList.get(position);

holder.view.setImageResource(image);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      ImageView view;

        ViewHolder(ImageView view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
        }
    }


}
```